# Why doesn't my direct descendant selector work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I have a problem with my direct descendant selector. Look at a simple example:

```css
.myDiv > table tr:first-child td {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:37%">Revenue & Cost</td>
      <td style="width:43%">Name</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Income</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>column 1</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table id="tableChild" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>child 1 - Should NOT bold</td>
            <td>child 2 - Should NOT bold</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

As you can see, it will effect table id **tableChild**. I expect to get a bold font on the first row on the first table.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85t8qm5r/)

Comment: It's selecting the first child of *any* `tr` element

Comment: You have two `td`s that are first children; the one with your headers is the first child of the outer table, and the one with the NOT bold content is the first child of that inner table. Maybe use <th> for headers instead?

Comment: @mherzig not maybe, `th` should always be used for headers that's what that element is specifically for.

Comment: @Martin agreed, I was being too nice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, finish defining the table correctly:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> TITLE ROW HERE </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    CONTENT ROWS HERE
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then your CSS selector becomes:

```
.myDiv>table>thead>tr>td {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do not know about this. I am a beginner with HTML. I learn a new thing today. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The browser fills in your missing table elements:

Try this:

```
.myDiv > table > tbody > tr:first-child td
```

https://jsfiddle.net/85t8qm5r/3/

Comment: The problem is not the selector not matching the right elements, it's that the selector is matching the wrong elements. (Your selector is correct; it's just the reasoning that's off.)

Comment: @BoltClock, from the question: *I expect to get a bold font on the first row on the first table.* The selector in the question was missing a DOM element, missed by the author but added-in by the browser.

Comment: The selector is using a descendant combinator, not a child combinator, so it doesn't have to specify tbody. It's matching all the right elements just fine - the problem is that it's also matching the cells in the nested table, which is not what the asker wants. It's the use of the descendant combinator that's problematic, not the missing tbody, although the solution does require specifying tbody in the selector.

Comment: @BoltClock, maybe I should have explained that in the answer. I took it for granted that the switch to the child combinator would be understood (since OP was using both). Thanks for the clarification.